# how do i go from a datatable to a hierarchical structure in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, hierarchical-data

I have a datatable which i get from the databasemanager class, 
and i would need to transform that data into a hierarchical structure

either binding it directly to a .net treeview control or in memory first .

i have an ID column, and a ParentID column.
what i do not know necessarily is the parent ID to start with. so first thing to do would be to find out which node is the parent ID.

what would be best practice to loop over this table and make it hierarchical

```
BranchId     ParentId    ProductCount    HasBranchChildren       Name
0           NULL        48              1                       Categories
1           0           20              1                       CategoryA
2           1           10              1                       CategoryA1
3           1           8               0                       CategoryA2
4           1           2               0                       CategoryA3
5           2           4               0                       CategoryA1.1
6           2           6               0                       CategoryA1.2
7           0           28              1                       CategoryB
8           7           20              0                       CategoryB1
9           7           8               0                       CategoryB2
```

this would be an example datatable
of course it will have hundreds of items, and it does not always start at the root node,
its possible that with a request a certain subset of categories is requested, 
however i've talked with the database team and they will give me NULL on root nodes
in the above example that would be element 0 in the table ....

Comment: what does your databasemanager class look like? can you post some code pls?

Comment: the database manager is not something we wrote, it returns datatables from stored procedures, technically i am not the one to change those but if a stored procedure needs changing i can ask that of the database team... i'll edit my post with an example datatable

Comment: aren't all records with no `parentID` automatically under the root? Or do you have 1 record which is the root element?

Comment: is the question how to create a tree from a table with relations or is the question how to bind the resulting tree to the tree view?

Comment: @Bazzz yes there could be multiple root elements in the returned data, and i've discussed with the db team they will give me a NULL when its root.

Comment: @ntziolis the question is how to get from a flat table ultimately to a treeview control in .net, i'm not talking a telerik control, just the default control.

Comment: @Sander I have updated my answer to include the creation of the tree, also taking care of your multi root requirement, regarding binding the Tree to the tree view, you can hardcore this, so it would create actual Tree view items, or you use some component that lets you bind an arbitrary Tree to any hierarchical control (and remember, you will run into this issue again ;).

Comment: just nitpicking: `ProductCount` and `HasBranchChildren` columns are pointless as they need to be updated everytime something changes in the table, leading to more troubles than solutions. Using subqueries to compute the columns might introduce overhead but it's definitely much better than the current solution.

Comment: @devnull those 2 columns are only for the initial state, when a user checks 1 of the checkboxes or filters or opens up a subtree, new queries are made to update these values. and the hasChildren was initially meant to set the TreeNode.PopulateOnDemand = true/false; though i'm not sure i'll need that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1.
You need to create a tree structure from a table in memory from, this should be simple. Checkout this question here:
[Most efficient way of creating tree from adjacency list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654627/most-efficient-way-of-creating-tree-from-adjacency-list)

Here is some code for your multi root case (I did not want to modify the parent values to some bogus value, therefore the virtual root and its immediate children will have parent = null, but that doe not matter for traversing the tree, since you have Children and IsRoot):

```
public class Branch
{
    public Branch()
    {
        Children = new List<Branch>();
    }

    public bool IsRoot { get; set; }
    public int? BranchId { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public List<Branch> Children { get; set; }

    public int ProductCount { get; set; }       
    public int HasBranchChildren { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    //other data
}

public class BranchTreeHelper
{
    public Branch MakeTree() 
    {
        var virtualRoot = new Branch()
        {
            BranchId = null,
            ParentId = null,
            IsRoot = true
        };

        // get the data from db, just disregard the properties: Children and IsRoot flage
        List<Branch> branchList = GetDataFromDB();

        var branchDict = branchList.ToDictionary(i => i.BranchId.Value, i => i);

        foreach(var branch in branchList)
        {
            if(branch.ParentId.HasValue)
            {
                branchDict[branch.ParentId.Value].Children.Add(branch);
            }
            else
            {
                virtualRoot.Children.Add(branch);
            }
        }

        return virtualRoot;
    }
}
```

Step 2. 
Sadly MS made it difficult, by not offering a simple generic way to bind to hierarchical data. But luckily others have created code that can. Use this to bind your new tree structure to a tree view:
http://ohds.codeplex.com/

From the project homepage:

> ObjectHierarchicalDataSource is to
>   hierarchical data sources what
>   ObjectDataSource is to tabular data
>   sources. It enables the page developer
>   to declaratively bind hierarchical
>   controls such as Menu and TreeView to
>   almost any object graph.

You could create you're own custom implementation of [IHierarchicalDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ihierarchicaldatasource.aspx) but I would strongly advise against that since this is cumbersome and error prone.

Option 2:
If you do not want to use third party user controls the checkout this **generic implementation of IHierarchicalDataSource** this again can be bound to any hierarchical ASP.NET control:
http://elegantcode.com/2008/04/06/aspnet-hierarchicaldatasourcet/

Comment: hey, i was reading upon that option 2, but that seems like a huge strain on the system, because in order to implement that solution i do not only need to create the tree like your code, with items having a children list, but every item would also need a parent property with the parent's Branch element in it. I am going to try that objectHierarchicalDataSource first :) we'll see what comes out

Comment: If you're worried about memory consumption, all the branches are loaded anyway, and as long as those are classes and structs you can reference them as often as you want without increasing memory usage noticeably (goes for Parent as well as Children references). If the lists are the issue, you should be able to replace them with arrays with some changes. But as long as you'e not working with enormous amounts of data, this should be sufficient. Can you tell us how much data and frequency of access were talking about?

Comment: I have no good view on the categories (branches) but the database holds around 20k products, obviously stored in alot of categories, but if i should make an estimated guess i'd say around 400 - 500 branches in the tree, (main and subcategories together)
though this does not mean all 400 at once... upon openinng a parent item, it will append the sub branches, the structure described above is just for the initial load after a search, usually the above structure will just be the first level with 1 branch opened till level 2 - 3 - 4 who knows....

Comment: by the way, i tried option 2, adding a parent to the branches, and it works, though i'm trying to find out whether its possible to manipulate what is bound to the tree, as i believe it now binds the name as value of the TreeNode, while the BranchId would be a more logical choice...

Comment: ok, so 400-500 branches should not be a problem to handle within memory. The fact that those branches map to that many products does not really matter until you start connecting those two structurally. Depending on how often branch configuration changes I would recommend caching the entire tree. T prevent you from searching through the tree I would additionally store the dict of branches to, this will give you access to a specific branch in O(1) and from there you can traverse the tree through the children. overhead is minimal since the branches are already in memory + the hashes for the dict

Comment: yeah, tough i will need to go trough the tree as well, upon submit i will need to know which treeNodes are Checked (checkboxes are in front of the items as they are used as filter) but i see it goes very well at the moment, with quite alot of items as test. time will tell if we need to find caching solutions for now this is not a priority but its on the list!   thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

The root node(s) will/must have the ParentId property null or 0 or some value that tells you that they don't have a parent node. Then you can start to search recursively for the nodes that have the current node id as parent. If all you want to do is display the collection in a tree, there's no need to keep it in memory in a hierarchical structure, you can just go ahead and build the tree. Something like this:

```
// just a concept, not tested, might have errors

// ObjectWithHierarchy could look something like this
class ObjectWithHierarchy
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int? ParentId {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

private void LoadTree()
{
    // initialize your collection of objects
    List<ObjectWithHierarchy> list = new List<ObjectWithHierarchy>();

    // build the tree
    TreeView treeView = new TreeView();

    foreach (var item in list.FindAll(i => i.ParentId == null))
    {
        // create the root node
        TreeNode rootNode = new TreeNode();
        rootNode.Text = item.Name; 
        rootNode.Tag = item;

        // load child nodes
        LoadChildNodes(node, list);

        // add the node to the treeview
        treeView.Nodes.Add(rootNode);
    }
}

private void LoadChildNodes(TreeNode node, List<ObjectWithHierarchy> list)
{
    ObjectWithHierarchy item = node.Tag as ObjectWithHierarchy;
    foreach (var childItem in list.FindAll(i => i.ParentId == item.Id))
    {
        // create the child node
        TreeNode childNode = new TreeNode();
        childNode.Text = childItem.Name;
        childNode.Tag = childItem;

        // load children, if there are any
        LoadChildNodes(childNode, list);

        // add it to its parent nodes collection
        node.Nodes.Add(childNode);
    }
}
```

There are some third party controls that "know" how to display a hierarchical structure if they know the Id and ParentId properties.

EDIT: just noticed that you're using ASP.NET, and the code is for a winforms treeview, but the concept is roughly the same.

Comment: Actually its enough when the parent's parent points to a node that does not exist. I have seen this before when null values where not allowed and no values could be excluded. It's ugly but it works and in these cases were the only option.